# メンテナンスのお知らせ：1月20日 (金) 11:00〜14:00 JST

Tags: 討議

[追加のメンテナンスのお知らせ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385873/314875)です。前回 2023 年 1 月 14 日のメンテナンス期間中に追加の時間が必要であることが判明しましたが、サイトの読み取り専用期間が長くなってしまうことを避けるため延長をとりやめました。

つきましては継続のため、日本時間 1 月 20 日 金曜 11 時 ( 1 月 20 日 金曜 02:00 UTC / 1 月 19 日 木曜 21:00 EST )  から約 3 時間の間、追加のシステムメンテナンスを実施します。この期間中、サイトは読み取り専用になります。たくさんの開発者が直面する技術的な問題を解決するために Stack Overflow をご利用くださっていることを理解しておりますが、もしダウンタイムが発生した場合にはできるだけ早く状況を解決できるよう努めますので、何卒ご理解のほどよろしくお願いいたします。ご不便をおかけして申し訳ございません。

詳細は [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385873/314875) 或いは [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/) などでもご確認いただけます。

---

以下、終了済みのメンテナンスです。

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385873/314875) に示されているように、日本時間 2023 年 1 月 14 日 土曜 8:00 ( 1 月 13 日 金曜 23:00 UTC / 18:00 EST ) から約 3 時間、システムメンテナンスを実施します。一部のサービスやプラットフォーム機能の中断が発生する場合もあります。ご不便をおかけして申し訳ございませんが、ダウンタイムが発生した場合はできるだけ早く状況を解決できるよう努めます。詳細は MSE 或いは [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/) などでもご確認いただけます。

問題に対処するために懸命に取り組んでおりますので、ご理解とご協力のほどよろしくお願いいたします。